# Get Most(Top) Rated Products in Magento2

Tags: magento2, ratings, magento-2.1.9

I am using Magento 2.1.9 version.
I need to get `Top Rated Product Collection` without using object manager.
How to get it.
I referred [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191012/magento-2-how-to-display-top-rated-products)

I used the below code in `Namespace\Module\Block\Product\Toprated.php`:

```
public function getTopRatedProducts() {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $reviewFactory = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory::class);
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->load();
    $rating = array();
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
        if($ratingSummary!=null){
            $rating[$product->getId()] = $ratingSummary;
        }
    }
    return $rating;
}
```