# Any free extension for displaying top rated products in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, module, extensions, product-review

I like to know is there any free extension or module for displaying top rated products in magento 2?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191037/68018

Answer (score 0):

You can Free Product List extension by Land Of COder

https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-product-list.html